# How to use received data by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

This code works well and I am receiving data from server. Data consists of `[{id: someId, name: someName}, {..}....{...}]`

```
SJA.ajax(dataToSend, function (respond) {
  if (respond) {
     for (var i in respond) {
        console.log(respond[i].id);
        console.log(respond[i].name);
      }
   }
});
```

How can I create an array from only `respond[i].name` and use this array in such a way:

```
var data = ["name", "name",  "name"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
var names = respond.map(function(r) { return r.name; });
```

will do what you want.

Comment: How r.name, it should be r ie return r;

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $.map(respond, function (v) { return v.name; });
```